# How to find whtere the point cross boundary

Tags: geometry

I have a line and it's angle, and a Point P(x,y), I need to find whether the Point P crosses the line, If the angle of line is 0,90,180 etc.. I can find it easily, but the angle can be any value between 0-360. Is there any equation for solving this problem?

```
                     *p2(x,y)
                     /
                    /
                   /
                  /          *P(x,y) ---> Need to find whether the Point
                 /                        P cross the boundary represented 
                /                         by Points p1 and p2
               /         /|__________
              /         / Direction  |  
             /          \  __________|
            /            \| 
           /
         *p1(x,y)
```

Thanks
Haris

Comment: is it homework ?

Comment: by "cross", you mean "on the line", or you want to know if it is left or right to the line ?  And in the first case, is it on the infinite line, or exclusively on the segment P1P2 ?

Comment: Hint for all case: do you know how to write the distance from P to the line ?